# How to set JSONArray in model attribute in spring modelandview controller?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to add JSONArray in spring's model attribute and return from ModelAndView Controller. Not able to do like below. Request for help. Thanking you!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView seatRequest( ModelMap model,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) throws JSONException, JsonProcessingException {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("0", "val0");
    jsonObject.put("1", "val1");
    jsonObject.put("2", "val2");
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    model.addAttribute("jsonData",jsonArray.toString());

    return new ModelAndView("sample");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention? Currently JsonArray is added in String form.You can access this jsonArray as a String in your view. But I think you don't want to do that. If you want to access it as object just add as  `model.addAttribute("jsonData",jsonArray)` and then you can access it as object in your views.

Also, In your json Object, Key value is Numric "0","1" so on. make it alphanumeric i.e "key1", "key2" etc. and values "val1","val2" etc.  Because name of identifiers cannot start with numbers.